# Parallelize data import from mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb

How to import data in parallel manner from mongodb. A solution is to scan all the mongodb, lets say it is 1000 rows there. And then to split, and fetch them in 100's batches and then combine them again so all are 1000.

Below is the code to import data to python from mongodb.

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient


def _connect_mongo(host, port, username, password, db):
    """ A util for making a connection to mongo """

    if username and password:
        mongo_uri = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (username, password, host, port, db)
        conn = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    else:
        conn = MongoClient(host, port)


    return conn[db]


def read_mongo(db, collection, query={}, host='localhost', port=27017, username=None, password=None, no_id=True):
    """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

    # Connect to MongoDB
    db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, username=username, password=password, db=db)

    # Make a query to the specific DB and Collection
    cursor = db[collection].find(query)

    # Expand the cursor and construct the DataFrame
    df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

    # Delete the _id
    if no_id:
        del df['_id']

    return df
```

Comment: Why do you think combining is faster than a single cursor? Have you consider using indexes?

Comment: @pobe how to do it using a cursor ?

Comment: well why would a query won't work?

Comment: @pobe the above works, but it takes 45 minutes. I want to speed up the process

Comment: As of my first comment, have you tried optimizing your database by using indexes? If the database is slow, I don't think parallelizing will improve it. If you still want to go with parallel, call read_mongo with multiple threads.

Comment: @Pobe can you please add this as a solution with modifcaiton to the code so it is clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said my comment, have you tried optimizing your database by using indexes? If the database is slow, I don't think parallelizing will improve it. If you still want to go with parallel, call read_mongo with multiple threads.

For indexes you should check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

There's no code related thing to add here, you just need to better understand your databases.

As for the code, python has concurrent (threads) or parallelism (multiprocessing package). You'd need to make your program call `read_mongo` with your already define/split queries.

There are many examples out there. I'd try the indexes before because it will help for the parallel stuff after.

Comment: thank you for the link. So to include indexing, is there something to be modified in the code or in the actual mongodb itself ?

Comment: mongo itself. I had a problem similar to yours and indexing solved it.

Comment: did you use robo 3T ?

Comment: you say _-call read_mongo with multiple threads.__ what is the code for that ?

Comment: the mongodb has a field "_id" does that mean it is indexed ? or do I index on that